# Como deletar objetos dentro de uma lista?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lista, delete

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
using (Context contexto = new Context())
{
    List<Cliente> listCliente = contexto.Cliente.Where(x => x.Status == 0).ToList();
}
```

Como faço para deletar do banco esse resultado? Lembrando que tenho inúmeros relacionamentos que também gostaria de deletar.

Algo do tipo:

```
using (Context contexto = new Context())
{
    List<Cliente> listCliente = contexto.Cliente.Where(x => x.Status == 0).ToList();

    foreach(Cliente objCliente in lilstCliente)
    {
        contexto.Cliente.Remove(objCliente);
    }
    contexto.SaveChanges();
}
```

Ao rodar dá o seguinte erro:

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Ao invés do:

```
contexto.Cliente.Remove(objCliente);
```

Tentei também:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry deb = contexto.Entry(entity);
deb.State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

E deu o mesmo erro.

Atualizando o caso:

Bom, como ainda não descobri como fazer de forma genérica essa exclusão em cascata e preciso colocar isso em produção, por enquanto estou tratando objeto por objeto, e como provavelmente não previ todos os relacionamentos possíveis, fiz de forma que quando dê algum erro de chave estrangeira, grave esse erro e sei que preciso fazer um tratamento a mais, basta atualizar o serviço em questão.

O objeto que quero excluir pode ter vários relacionamentos, e esses relacionamentos podem ter outros relacionamentos, todos dependendo do objeto que quero excluir. Ex: quero excluir cliente, o cliente tem um processo, o processo tem histórico. Ou seja, se eu excluir o cliente, quero que tanto o processo quanto o histórico do processo sejam excluídos também.

Comment: Tente entender isso aqui : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538974/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-pro.

Estou sem tempo agora, se não tentava te ajudar melhor, mas parece que isto ali resolve. Abraço

Comment: Você precisa mostrar os models que fazem relação com clientes.

Comment: @Bruno No caso do link que você passou, ele precisa fazer um tratamento em cada objeto que depende do objeto principal, certo? Então, eu gostaria de saber se tem como fazer tipo um delete cascade. Todos objetos que dependem do objeto principal precisariam ser deletados.

Comment: @LINQ Preciso dar um include em todos os objetos que dependem do objeto cliente? Não entendi muito bem o comentário.

Comment: Ah, você quer configurar um cascade delete para os dependentes de `Cliente`?

Comment: @LINQ Mais ou menos isso, mas pelo c# ou alguma funcionalidade do entity framework, tem como? Não pelo banco ou edmx, entende?

Comment: Tem como sim, perai

Comment: Como esta configurado seu DbContext ?  veja seu método OnModelCreating se esta configurado para não fazer delete em Cascade. modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Não tem nada nele, além do padrão "throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException()".

Answer (score 1):

Por padrão o EntityFramework já faz o deletecascade por default, apenas se você desligar ele com o seguinte comando ele não o fará:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
}
```

No seu caso você tem um relacionamento `1-0:1` assim o `Entityframework` não sabe o que fazer quando tem um valor `null`, ele não consegue fazer o delete. Esse é um limite do `EntityFramework` < 6 e não tem o que fazer

Sugestão:

1. Como informado, delete os registros-filhos manualmente.
2. Existem diversas bibliotecas que estendem o EntityFramework como o http://entityframework-plus.net/ tente encontrar algo que faça isso.

---

Sobre os 2 comandos que você executou
Na entidade 6.0 há uma diferença entre:

```
context.Cliente.Remove(entity);
```

e

```
context.Entry(Cliente).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

Ao usar o primeiro, cascata estão habilitados, a EF executará internamente as eliminações necessárias para os registros-filho. Ao usar a segunda opção, a EF não irá lidar com as eliminações necessárias.